Allowing a github actions runner (self-hosted Windows EC2) to access the UI?
I have a github actions self-hosted runner on an AWS EC2 instance (Windows) running under a particular user. That is, it is not running as a service, which I understand would block it from accessing the Windows UI. I also have a Python bot (under the Robocorp platform) which requires interacting with the Windows UI, specifically the robocorp-windows library. This library works fine on the same machine, with the same Windows user, when running my bot through Robocorp's Control Room as you should in production, ie, using their tooling. It also runs fine if I RDP into the runner while the tests are running.
However, the library doesn't work when running via the github actions runner without me logging into the machine. Robocorp (which is generally a fantastic platform and their tech support is usually great) is telling me that "UI automation needs to have a 'head' so it's probably unlikely to work without one" and that "this is a limitation of any windows UI library, not specific or enforced by the robocorp-windows library". However, it's evidently possible for this to be done somehow since, as I said, their tooling is a able to run these Windows functions even while I'm not logged in. Specifically, they instruct you to configure the Robocorp process with the Use Desktop Connection option. However, they respond that "this is handled by our tooling and configurations are not publicly available". Essentially they're telling me I will never be able to run CI/CD for the bots that use this (or any) Windows library.
In conclusion, I'm hoping to achieve the same RDP magic they achieve with their tooling but with the github runner. Is this reasonable? Should I ask the GitHub Actions team this question directly?
